# Http Redirect within web.config using wildcards not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, visual-studio-2015, iis-express, iis-8

My need is to tell IIS, within the web.config to ignore some URLs and to send a HttpRedirect to the client.

To do so, I added the following magic into web.config :

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpRedirect enabled="true" httpResponseStatus="Temporary" exactDestination="true"> 
        <add wildcard="*/iac*; " destination="http://someServer.smthg.be/iac$S$Q" />
    </httpRedirect>
</system.webServer>
```

When I try to make a request, to eg ´myserver/iac/john?doe=hello´ I only receive a 404 not found instead of the 302 I expected.

Comment: I really hate writing "not working" in questions, if ever you find a better title, do not hesitate to suggets an edit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <clear />
            <rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^iac/(.*)" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://someServer.test.be/iac/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Temporary" />
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
```

Comment: as is, your solution redirects every URL and does not take into account the query string

Comment: your answer helped me to find a way. I updated your answer with one working